# HTTPS showing not secure with NGINX (DigitalOcean Droplet)

Tags: ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate, digital-ocean, certbot

I have a domain name (https://www.maltemafrica.com) and another (https://academy.maltemafrica.com/)
Both domains were working just fine for 2 months until today, it's not secure anymore.

The operating system my web server runs on is: Ubuntu

My hosting provider is: DigitalOcean

The version of my certbot is 0.28.0

I ran this command: `certbot renew --dry-run`

It produced this output:
`Attempting to renew cert (academy.maltemafrica.com) from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/academy.maltemafrica.com.conf produced an unexpected error: Requesting acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory: Network is unreachable. Skipping.`

I ran this command: `curl -v https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory`

It produced this output:

```
Trying 23.75.3.165…
TCP_NODELAY set
Connected to acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org (23.75.3.165) port 443 (#0)
ALPN, offering h2
ALPN, offering http/1.1
successfully set certificate verify locations:
CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
```

Comment: `Host academy.maltemafrica.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)` but `maltemafrica.com has address 184.168.221.91` looks like you have no IP address defined for your host.

Comment: I saw you solved the issue. Can you post the solution?